# Effecient Coding for low end CPU

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a application built in Silverlight, which will run on a ATOM processor (was told around 1.6GHZ).
So far tested another application with lesser functions on another Mini PC and it can still run smoothly.
This application will be user interactive, and will have 4-5 different pages to be displayed.
So to navigate from page to page, I currently have 2 options, but not sure which is a better way considering the low end CPU. (pages are static, nothing generated on the fly)

1)Load the 4 - 5 pages during the onLoad event, shown the 1st page using Visibility.Visible.
The other pages will be Visibility.Collasped. This way, only need to toggle the Visibility property, pages need not be destroyed and re-created.

2)Initialize all the pages when loaded. Use Container.child to attach the wanted page. Not sure about the capability about this, but for other applications, I usually choose this method.

*P/S: I am okay if it takes a while to load,as the application will be loaded only once per day. As long as during the running period, it does not lag(using touchscreen) I am more than happy.

Comment: Are you having a problem?...   Haven't tried anything?

Comment: Cant get to try, tested on a sample PC for another application. The actual PC for this application will come around 2 weeks b4 my app is deployed. Hence cannot wait till last min then try to figure out which is a better option

Comment: What you describe here is an optimization tradeoff. I suggest you build the unoptimized version first (the simplest design - probably load on-demand). If your design is clean, switching between the two should not be more than a day's work. You can budget for this day at project start, and if the simple design suffices, you have a day extra for features and bugfixes.

Comment: @jdv, will take ur vote on using the load-on demand, design wise I would say that it will be quite complicated, thats where the problem comes as every freak thing need to be as customizable as possible. 1 group of people will say they want color A, when deploy, it will be used by another group of users which will then for example say color B,hence troublesome on this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick is to keep effects to a minimum. Animations etc. - not a problem in a normal application, more in a game or something. For normal LOB style apps, the CPU would not be too busy anyway.

Comment: In terms of animation, you can say there is currently none. Perhaps will only show a small area of video. Video should not be more than 768 X 150 in size. But backend will be having quite some communication over Socket

Comment: THen you should be fine. VIdeo depends on decoding which may or may not be a problem - depends on the driver / gpu side, not on the CPU. You have to try that one out.

Comment: I think there is an option in Silverlight project properties, checked the use GPU option. Hope it will do just fine